# What does Passing a template handler in the template name is deprecated. mean?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I've been trying to figure out what this error message means, but can't figure it out.

Here is the full message

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing a template handler in the template name
is deprecated. You can simply remove the handler name or pass render
:handlers => [:jbuilder] instead. (called from realtime at
/Users/Arel/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/1.9.1/benchmark.rb:295)
```

and here is the code:

```
it "is logged in" do
    post "/api/v1/login", user_login: {email: 'test@test.com', password: '12345678' }
    response.status.should be(201)
  end
```

What is a `template handler`, and why does it think I'm passing it in the `template name`? What template?

EDIT:

`Sessions_controller`. The controller being called by the login path.

```
class Api::V1::SessionsController < Devise::SessionsController
    before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:create, :destroy]
    before_filter :ensure_params_exist
    skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token

  def create
    resource = User.find_for_database_authentication(email: params[:user_login][:email])
    return invalid_login_attempt unless resource

    if resource.valid_password?(params[:user_login][:password])
        sign_in("user", resource)
        resource.ensure_authentication_token!
        render 'api/v1/sessions/new.json.jbuilder', status: 201
        return
    end
    invalid_login_attempt
  end

  def destroy
        current_user.reset_authentication_token
        render json: {success: true}
  end

  protected

  def ensure_params_exist
    return unless params[:user_login].blank?
    render json: {success: false, message: "missing user_login parameter"}, status: 422
  end

  def invalid_login_attempt
    render 'api/v1/sessions/invalid.json.jbuilder', status: 401
  end
end
```

Comment: Post your controller code. What controller does `/api/v1/login` point to?

Comment: the compiler thinks you are registering a handle to a JS framework template. This problem seems to happen often in rspec. I don't have a better answer, but please post your controller code.

Comment: Just added the controller code.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

When rendering from your controller action, you no longer need to pass the file format or handler as part of the file name. Instead, you'd do this:

```
render 'api/v1/sessions/new', :formats => [:json], :handlers => [:jbuilder], status: 201
```

This provides convenience for actions that render out in multiple formats. For instance, rather than rendering a separate template for each of the formats, you can simply pass an array of accepted formats to `render`:

```
render 'api/v1/sessions/foo', :formats => [:html, :js, :xml]
#=> handles html, js, and xml requests
#=> renders to foo.html, foo.js, and foo.xml, respectively
```

Passing an array to `:builders` allows you to specify the template builder(s) to use when rendering:

```
render 'api/v1/sessions/foo', :formats => [:json], :handlers => [:jbuilder]
#=> renders to foo.json.jbuilder
```

Comment: Great answer and explanation! Thanks!